# Linux partition screwed up by Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning

I have 2 disks, `sda` and `sdb`. `sda` has a bunch of partitions, including a Windows 10 partition, and an Ubuntu partition. `sda` isn't the problem.

`sdb` has (er... had) a single partition, created from ubuntu. I just used it for some extra storage.

I booted up Windows, and *opened* the program "Disk Partition", so I could futz around with some stuff on `sda`. However, *just opening the program* resulted in a popup (identical to the one shown below).

I carelessly clicked "GPT" because

1. I knew it *wasn't* a "Master Boot Record" partition,
2. I didn't really *care* about what *it* thought the partition was- I wasn't interested in doing anything with that drive!, and
3. It was a dialog that popped up *just on opening the program*, and there's 0 language indicating that the actions taken by the popup could be potentially destructive.

So, I clicked "OK", and there was no delay or anything, "confirming" (or so I thought...) that the dialog box was inconsequential.

Except *now*, I can't mount that partition from ubuntu because `fdisk -l` shows

`/dev/sdb1 .... Size: 128M, Type: Microsoft reserved`, and then in red it says `Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary`.
It was *previously* a 1 TB partition (the full size of the disk).

So- 1. What can I do to recover the disk? *Can* I recover the disk? Where do I go from here?

---

Update (by Kamil Maciorowski) [thanks!]:

[image: picture]

Comment: Was the popup like the one in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld8v7.png)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - yes! exactly that. Why the hell does it not say "hey if you think there's content on this disk, saying 'OK' will screw things up..." or anything *remotely* like that... Anyways. What can I do from here?

Comment: I added the picture to your question. You can [edit] and make the whole thing more coherent.

Comment: You may find these questions of interest: [*Will initializing disk make data unrecoverable?*](https://superuser.com/q/283930/432690) [*Accessing data on drive that was initialized as a GPT*](https://superuser.com/q/1154147/432690), [*Accidentally initialized hard disk with important data*](https://superuser.com/q/862543/432690).